# Scraping special graphical characters in an HTML table

Tags: python, html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a [table](https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/rating), which in some cells has a "graphical" element (arrow up/down) using R. Unfortunately, the library `rvest` function `html_table` seems to skip these elements. This is how such a cell with arrow looks like in HTML:

```
<td>
    <span style="font-weight: bold; color: darkgreen">Ba2</span>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" title="negative outlook"></i>
</td>
```

The code I am using is:

```
require(rvest)
require(tidyverse)

url = "https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/rating"
#bypass company firewall
download.file(url, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)
content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")
tables <- content %>% html_table(fill = TRUE, trim=TRUE)
```

But for example for the cell above, it gives me only `Ba2` string. Is there a way to include also the arrows somehow (as text, e.g. `Ba2 neg`)? Solution in Python would be also useful, if R does not have such functionality.

Thank you!

Comment: Those arrows are called ```font-awesome``` icons. I don't think you can get those arrows as they are not text. Instead you can show (up/down) or some other indicator for Up-arrow and Down-arrow. Like ```Ba2(Up)```.

Comment: I meant getting the arrows as a flag instead - `glyphicon-arrow-down` would be in text 'neg' for example - so the cell would be `Ba2 neg` if there is an arrow down

Comment: Yes, you can get that. I don't know about R but in Python you can do that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is possible in R but in Python this will give you the required results.

I have tried to print the first few rows to give you an idea of how the data looks.

> `pos` - Denotes Arrow-up and `neg` - Denotes Arrow-down

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/country-list/rating'

resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')


t = soup.find('table', attrs= {'id': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_GridView1'})
tr = t.findAll('tr')

for i in range(1,10):
    tds = tr[i].findAll('td')
    temp = []
    for j in tds:
        fa_down = j.find('i', class_='glyphicon-arrow-down')
        fa_up = j.find('i', class_='glyphicon-arrow-up')
        if fa_up:
            print(f'{j.text.strip()} (pos)')
        elif fa_down:
            print(f'{j.text.strip()} (neg)')
        else:
            print(f'{j.text.strip()}')
```

```
Output: 

+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|  Field 1   | Field 2 |  Field 3  |  Field 4  | Field 5 | Field 6 |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|  Albania   |    B+   |     B1    |           |         |    35   |
|  Andorra   |   BBB   |           |    BBB+   |         |    62   |
|   Angola   |   CCC+  |    Caa1   |    CCC    |         |    21   |
| Argentina  |   CCC+  |     Ca    |    CCC    |   CCC   |    15   |
|  Armenia   |         |    Ba3    |     B+    |         |    16   |
|   Aruba    |   BBB   |           |     BB    |         |    52   |
| Australia  |   AAA   |    Aaa    | AAA (neg) |   AAA   |   100   |
|  Austria   |   AA+   |    Aa1    |    AA+    |   AAA   |    96   |
| Azerbaijan |   BB+   | Ba2 (pos) |    BB+    |         |    48   |
+------------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```